# how to snap (align) edge to (with) a vertex in another object

Tags: modeling

I'm new to blender and am having a difficult time with very simple tasks, such as moving an edge in one object to align with (snap to) a vertex in another object.

I want to grab the right vertical internal edge inside the upper rectangle and move (translate it) to the right so that it aligns with the upper-right vertex in the rectangle below . . .

I've tried "Snap during transform", "Snap to vertices", and tried "Closest", "Active", "Median" and "Center". I pressed G to grab the edge, but it won't snap to the vertex on the lower square.  I also tried regular "Snap", but it collapses the entire edge to a single point.

I think I've tried everything, but nothing has worked. Many thanks for any advice!

[image]

Comment: Solution for this is actually to use Snap during transform. I can't tell what didn't work. If you enable it, select edge, press axis to move along, move it and hover over vertex to snap to it should snap. It could help you to find answer if you mention what didn't work and what happened

Comment: A ha! I think it seems to matter where I click with the cursor. If I click close to the element that I'm grabbing and dragging, then it snaps into place, but if I click farther away from where I'm "grabbing", then it doesn't snap.

Comment: As long as it doesn't find any elements it can snap to it won't snap. Mouse cursor position matters in this case as the element it hovers over is the one which will be snapped to.

Answer (score 2):

I think it *might* be that you're not moving the edge under a constraint, so you can't hover over the target without dragging the whole edge down to it.

The 'Active', 'Closest' etc. settings refer to the source of the snap, the moving element. The 'Vertex', 'Face', etc. button next door refers to the target, the still element.

The most intuitive setting, I think, is (source)'Active', (target)'Vertex', used with a selection of source *vertices* made, one of them active, aiming to align with a target vertex.

So try it that way, with all the vertices of your edge(loop?) selected, using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, constraining the move, leaving your mouse free to hover over the target vertex, without pulling the selection with it.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties tab, you can copy the global X coordinate of the vertex to the global X coordinates of the edge you want to align.

That works as long as everything is parallel to X. If it's not, well, er...

Make sure you're in global coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Many thanks, and much appreciated! While that answer works, as you point out, everything has to be normal to X and I also feel the approach could be somewhat labor intensive, so I'm also hoping to find a relatively simple solution involving dragging/dropping/grabbing, etc.

Comment: It's definitely a hassle